# Problemas con el objeto que genera jQuery al seleccionar varios elementos

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function toggleInputs(tipo, este) {
  if (tipo == "checkbox") {
    if ($(este).prop('checked')) {
      $(este).parent().addClass("palomeado");
    } else {
      $(este).parent().removeClass("palomeado");
    }
  } else if (tipo == "radio") {
    $(este).parents("form").children("label").removeClass("palomeado");
    $(este).parent().addClass("palomeado");
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  /*for (var i = 0; i < $("form input").length; i++) {
    objs = $("form").find("input")[i];
    console.info($("form input")[i].checked);
    if($("form input")[i].checked){
      objs.parent().addClass("palomeado");
    } else {
      objs.parent().removeClass("palomeado");
    }
  }*/

  $("form input").click(function() {
    toggleInputs($(this).attr("type"), $(this));
  });

});
```

```css
label {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #262626;
  margin: 1px 0;
  /*Algunas de estas propiedades las use en la fase de prueba, cambiar según necesidades*/
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

form[name=dias] {
  font-size: 24px;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {}

label.palomeado {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <form name="dias">
    <h1>Dias</h1>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" />
 1
    </label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" checked/>
 2
</label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" checked/>
 3
  </label>
  </form>

  <br><br><br>

  <form name="alojamiento">
    <h1>Alojamiento</h1>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id="" />
 <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
 </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id="" checked/>
 <i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
 </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id=""/>
 <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
 </label>
  </form>

  <br/><br/><br/>

  <form name="comida">
    <h1>Comida</h1>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="comida" id="" />
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
   </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="comida" id=""/>
 <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="comida" id=""checked/>
 <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Como podéis ver en el script cuando hago `click` en un `input` este ejecuta la función `toggleInputs` que en función de si es un `checkbox` o un `radio` hace que los `labels` aparenten estar presionados o no presionados con la clase "palomeado".

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que esta función solo se ejecuta al hacer `click` en los `inputs` y por lo tanto al si al cargar la pagina ya hay alguno de ellos marcado a estos no se les añade la clase "palomeado" y por lo tanto no aparentan presionados.

He probado muchas cosas con eventos `ready`, sin ellos y con bucles `for` para recorrer todos elementos pero siempre tengo problemas con jQuery porque cada vez que hago una selección y el target de esa selección son varios "objetos" este me crea un objeto de esos `{}` (perdón por mi falta de vocabulario) y se que puedo acceder a ellos con `[]` como si fuese un `Array` pero cuando quiero acceder a su padre o quitarle o añadirle una clase (ver código comentado) no lo considera como un objeto y me da un error parecido a esto:

> TypeErro: objs.parent() is not a function" o "obj.attr() is not a
>   function.

Y tampoco me puedo referir a el como `$(this)`. **Que se me está escapando? Como puedo solucionarlo?** Pero sobretodo me interesa entenderlo.

Comment: Espero que la sencillez de mi ejemplo y el enlace a la documentación sea suficiente para que entiendas como funciona. Si no es así házmelo saber y amplio algo más la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo te queda ejecutar la función por cada uno que esté pulsado con la siguiente iteración buscando el [selector `:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
$("form input:checked").each(function() {
  toggleInputs($(this).attr("type"), $(this));
});
```

Aquí tienes el ejemplo completo:

```js
function toggleInputs(tipo, este) {
  if (tipo == "checkbox") {
    if ($(este).prop('checked')) {
      $(este).parent().addClass("palomeado");
    } else {
      $(este).parent().removeClass("palomeado");
    }
  } else if (tipo == "radio") {
    $(este).parents("form").children("label").removeClass("palomeado");
    $(este).parent().addClass("palomeado");
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  /*for (var i = 0; i < $("form input").length; i++) {
    objs = $("form").find("input")[i];
    console.info($("form input")[i].checked);
    if($("form input")[i].checked){
      objs.parent().addClass("palomeado");
    } else {
      objs.parent().removeClass("palomeado");
    }
  }*/

  $("form input").click(function() {
    toggleInputs($(this).attr("type"), $(this));
  });
  $("form input:checked").each(function() {
    toggleInputs($(this).attr("type"), $(this));
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #262626;
  margin: 1px 0;
  /*Algunas de estas propiedades las use en la fase de prueba, cambiar según necesidades*/
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

form[name=dias] {
  font-size: 24px;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {}

label.palomeado {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <form name="dias">
    <h1>Dias</h1>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" />
 1
    </label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" checked/>
 2
</label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="dia" id="" checked/>
 3
  </label>
  </form>

  <br><br><br>

  <form name="alojamiento">
    <h1>Alojamiento</h1>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id="" />
 <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
 </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id="" checked/>
 <i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
 </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="alojamiento" id=""/>
 <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
 </label>
  </form>

  <br/><br/><br/>

  <form name="comida">
    <h1>Comida</h1>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="comida" id="" />
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
   </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="comida" id=""/>
 <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="comida" id=""checked/>
 <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Vaya, no conocía .each(), que interesante, investigaré sobre ello. Problema resuelto, muchísimas gracias! Pero de todas maneras, ¿porque no puedo hacer $("form input")[6].addClass?? Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: `$( ... )` devuelve una [instancia del objeto jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/jquery-object-instance-properties/) y no una matriz. Aunque podrías usar [`$( ... ).toArray()[6].addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) en su lugar.

Comment: Investigaré sobre ambos conceptos. Muchisimas gracias!